# Bootstrap datetimepicker $(...).datetimepicker is not a function, even after putting script in correct order

Tags: django, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using django-bootstrap4-datetimepicker. Below is the order in which I am including the needed javascript files. Even after that it is giving - **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block extra_head %}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/timeline.css' %}">

    {{ form.media }}
</head>
{% endblock %}
<div class="middle">
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</div>
</html>
```

Here is how I am using it in the HTML file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
            }
            $('#act_time').datetimepicker({
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
                maxDate: new Date(),
                minDate: new Date("{{ min_date.isoformat }}"),
          });
    });
```

Any hints/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got an element with `id="act_time"` in the html ?

Comment: Actually I have passed it through forms.                                      Forms.py - ` widgets = {
            'act_time': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'id': 'act_time', 'size': '10', 'height': '10px','font-size': '8px'}, format=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M']),
        }`

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Yes, I am getting - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function